# Map a caps lock key that is mapped to ctrl system wide to Escape just in vim

Tags: vim

i have mapped my caps lock key to ctrl with the following command under linux:

    `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`

I really like this mapping and want to keep it, but I also would like to map the caps lock key to Escape when I am inside vim. But when I try to map it with `:map <C> <Esc>` or similar it  does not seem to work, presumably because the ctrl key is special and needs a second key to to trigger an key event.

Is there any way I can achieve the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The control, shift and alt keys are handled differently at the hardware and OS levels - they do not generate keycodes but add modifiers to the keycodes generated by other keys.  This means that they cannot be mapped within Vim.

Comment: But you can remap it in Linux, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim

Answer (score 3):

Dave is right, you can't.
However, there are lots of alternatives to remap the escape key.
I personaly use ` which is close (on my keyboard) to the capslock key :-)
(as ' is pretty useless , you can remap ' to `)

```
noremap ' `
noremap ` <Esc>
```

Comment: It is true that there are lots of alternatives. Myself I have the Tab key mapped to Escape, which means I can do <C-i> instead of hitting Escape because in Vim Control + i is equivalent to the Tab key. This is quite an ok solution for me personally..