# Shift lock key acting like escape AND shift lock. How to only make it behave like escape using xmodmap?

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want my shift lock button to act like escape in linux(ubuntu) for in vim. I did the following in my home directory:

1. `xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'`
2. `xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap`
3. Create .xinitrc in home folder en paste:
   `xmodmap .Xmodmap` in that file.

resources:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys
[How to map CAPS LOCK key in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim)

The problem is that now my `shift lock` key is acting like `shift lock` AND `escape` at the same time, how can I change it to act solely like `escape`?

Comment: I can't test this at the moment but I think you should just be able to run `setxkbmap -o caps:escape` to make Caps Lock an additional Escape.

Comment: Using Xkb as @RandyMorris described would make the use of xmodmap superfluous (or maybe even detrimental).

Comment: Which Ubuntu/gnome version are you using? There is a better solution without using xmodmap.

Comment: @Magnus Leno: Ubuntu 11.10, Oneiric.

Comment: @echristopherson: why would it be detrimental? What would be your solution?

Comment: @Bentley4 I'm not sure it would be detrimental; it's just that xmodmap and setxkbmap use two different interfaces to the X server to modify key bindings, so there may or may not be a conflict. setxkbmap is the newer of the two, and the one most likely to keep working in the future.

Comment: Since you use Ubuntu 11.10, there is a better solution (in my opinion). Just forget about setxkbmap and xmodmap and use default gnome settings :D, just look at the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ubuntu 11.10+ (with Gnome 3 libraries) there is an "almost hidden" keyboard options which allows you to change many keys behaviors. To make **Caps Lock act like an additional ESC** follow these steps:

```
1. System -> Preferences -> Keyboard
2. Select Layouts tab, then Layout Options
3. Click on 'CapsLock key behavior'
4. Click on 'Swap ESC and CapsLock'
```

Here is a print screen:
[image: Gnome 3 - Make Caps Lock an additional ESC]

As shown above there are many other possibilities, like **"Swap ESC and Caps Lock"**. Also, if you miss your Caps Lock functionality, there is an option to "map Caps Lock behavior" for other keys/keys combinations. Just read all options, test a couple and pick your favorites.

Comment: That is a terrific hint. It is indeed well hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the command under the X window.

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"
```