# How to use Caps lock as Enter key in INSERT Mode in neovim

Tags: linux, terminal, neovim

I want to make
Caps lock key behave or act as Enter key, only insert mode.
In lua.

Answer (score 0):

Linux? Maybe you can try this:

```lua
vim.cmd[[
    au InsertEnter * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape' 
    au InsertLeave * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock'
]]
```

This question([How to map CAPS LOCK key in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim)) may be same as yours.